# extracting a value from data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, extract

I am trying to extract a single value from a data frame. Instead it returns the value and the levels of the variable (see below).

How do I make sure it only returns the value "defect" or "cooperate" without the levels?
'''

```
Response_1 = book[c("id1", "bid1")]
Response_2 = book[c("id2", "bid2")]

my_id = "3"

main_data1 = subset(Response_1,  Response_1$id1 %in% my_id)
main_data2 = subset(Response_2 , Response_2$id2 %in% my_id)
names(main_data2) = c("id1", "bid1")
names(main_data1) = c("id1", "bid1")

main_data = rbind(main_data1, main_data2)

print(main_data[length(main_data$bid1), 2])


> print(main_data[length(main_data$bid1), 2])
[1] cooperate
Levels: cooperate defect
```

Comment: Just use `as.character` as it is a `factor` column.   COnvert to `character` class by wrapping with `as.character`

Comment: thank you very much. This solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your original data structure was, since you haven't provided it, but when you use `rbind` you inherently call `data.frame`.  By default, `data.frame` has the argument `stringsAsFactors = T`

In general, you can fix this by calling your dataframe with `stringsAsFactors = F` or by manually adjusting the column with something like `df$column = as.character(df$column)`

In this particular case, if you don't want to recode the dataframe, do what akrun said and call `print(as.character(main_data[length(main_data$bid1), 2]))`